# vsftpd getting user home directory

Tags: linux, vsftpd

I have a vsftpd setup in a container. An issue was raised that one of the ftp user can access above his own home directory, even chroot is configured.

in /etc/passwd of container

`ftpuser1:x:996:996::/srv/ftp/./folder1/:/bin/bash`

However when ftpuser1 logged in from ftp and `cd /` then `ls`, instead it shows all other folders which are in `/srv/ftp/`, e.g. folder1, folder2, etc.

I was a bit suspicious of the `.` way of putting down the home dir in /etc/passwd, is there any reason to do that? I did not build the server and have no idea how it was configured this way.

Below is the vsftpd config

```html
anonymous_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=NO
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_address=123.123.123.123
pasv_min_port=40000
pasv_max_port=45000
anon_root=/srv/ftp/folder2
chroot_local_user=YES
passwd_chroot_enable=YES
pasv_promiscuous=yes
background=NO
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd/vsftpd.log
log_ftp_protocol=YES
debug_ssl=YES
```